# Display Parent, child and grandchild's records

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

Once a parent(Contact) is selected I have to display a list of related records from child, grandchild and grandchild's child in one single page block. All the objects are in a lookup relationship with their parent. The query which I'm writing is not getting saved and giving the error:
"Didn't understand relationship 'Grandchild__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name."
Please help me with apex, Wrapper class and VF code as well. 
Parent- Contact
Child- Child__c
Grandchild- Grandchild__c
Grandchild's child- GreatGrandChild__c
Below is my code.

Controller-

```
public with sharing class MyController {    
Public String name {get;set;}
Public String newContactName{get;set;}
Public Contact objContact{get;set;}
Public List<Child__c> cmList{get;set;}
Public List<Wrapper> wrapList{get;set;}
public Boolean flag{get;set;}
Public MyController(){
    flag =  true;
  objContact = new Contact(); 
}  

Public PageReference doSave(){
    try{
        insert objContact;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.Debug('In catch '+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
} 
public List<SelectOption> getContactList(){
    List<SelectOption> contactList = new List<SelectOption>();
    contactList.add(new SelectOption('-----Select----','-----Select----')); 
    List<Contact> conList = [select id , Name from Contact];
    for(Contact c :conList){
        contactList.add(new SelectOption(c.Id,c.Name));     
    }
   return  contactList;    
}

Public void showrecord(){
    wrapList = new List<Wrapper>();
    system.debug('inmethod');
    cmList = [Select id, Name, Contact__c, FieldA__c, (Select id, Name, Child__c, FieldB__c (Select id, Name, GrandChild__c, FieldC__c from GreatGrandChild__r) from GrandChild__r) from Child__c where Contact__c =: name];
    for(Child__c cm :cmList)
    {
        wrapList.add(new Wrapper(false,cm));
    }        
    system.debug('inmethod'+ cmList);
}
Public Class Wrapper{
    Public Boolean ischeck{get;set;}
    Public Child__c NCM{get;set;}
    Public Wrapper (Boolean ischeck, Child__c NCM){
        This.ischeck=ischeck;
        This.NCM=NCM;
    }    
}
}
```

Page-

```
     <apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >    
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts" rendered="{!flag}">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Name"/>
            <apex:selectlist value="{!name}" size="1" id="values"> 
                <apex:SelectOptions value="{!ContactList}"/>  
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showrecord}" reRender="con"/>          
            </apex:selectlist>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapList}" var="v" id="con">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!v.ischeck}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!v.NCM.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!v.NCM.Contact__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!v.NCM.FieldA__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!v.NCM.FieldB__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!v.NCM.FieldC__c}"/>                              
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!NOT(flag)}">

        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
      </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: I think in my query, I need to add Plural Label (GreatGrandChilds__r).

Comment: Go to your Child object -- Go to Grand_Child__c lookup field ---> Their you will see a data named Child Relationship Name. Use that for your query. Say if the child relationship name is XYZs then use XYZs__r in your query.

Comment: @Keith C- I can use two separate queries, but will that work to display all the records in one page block? In that case, do I need to wite one more wrapper class. Could you please help me with the sample code for the same.

Answer (score 4):

While you can go up 5 levels in the child to parent direction, you can only go down 1 level in parent to child relationships. See the "Understanding Relationship Query Limitations" section towards the end of the [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) documentation.

So you will need to use two separate queries. Here is one way to do that (might contain typos):

```
Map<Id, Child__c> children = new Map<Id, Child__c>([
        Select Id, Name, Contact__c, FieldA__c
        from Child__c
        where Contact__c = :name
        ]);
Map<Id, List<GrandChild__c>> grandChildren = new Map<Id, List<GrandChild__c>>;
for (GrandChild__c grandChild : [
        Select id, Name, Child__c, FieldB__c,
                (Select id, Name, GrandChild__c, FieldC__c from GreatGrandChild__r)
        from GrandChild__c
        where Child__c in :children.keySet()
        ]) {
    List<GrandChild__c> l = grandChildren.get(grandChild.Child__c);
    if (l == null) {
        l = new List<GrandChild__c>;
        grandChildren.put(grandChild.Child__c, l);
    }
    l.add(grandChild);
}
Set<Id> childIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Child__c child : children.values()) {
    List<GrandChild__c> l = grandChildren.get(child.Id);
    if (l = null) {
        l = new List<GrandChild__c>();
    }
    // Wrapper now has extra argument and field, the list of grand children with the
    // great grand children available in each grand child's GreatGrandChild__r field
    wrapList.add(new Wrapper(false, child, l));
}
```

You will need to check (or just try a few likely values) the name GreatGrandChild__r; normally this would be a plural so it might be GreatGrandChilds__r or GreatGrandChildren__r - that is a choice the person creating the data model makes.

Comment: Thanks for the code... Will try this and let you know....